# Is there a word for "one who decides (something)"?

Tags: expressions

"Decider" is not the word I am looking for. It is used only in context of a game. Can anyone help me with a word for "one who decides (something)", in general context?

Comment: [final] [authority](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/authority) ***a.** The power to enforce laws, exact obedience, command, determine, or judge. **b. One that is invested with this power***

Comment: If you want a single word, I recommend *arbiter.*  Though *decision-maker* is by far the most common term, it is quite long and unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one phrase that is commonly used is "decision maker." There are other, specialized words or phrases for many domains. By the way, the word "decider" is not only used in the context of a game - for instance, George W. Bush said of himself (when explaining his view that every process has to have one final decision maker) "Well, I'm the decider."

Comment: +1 for the reference to W, the sage of our time! (Sarcasm!)

Comment: sage n. Either of two bushy North American plants with silvery-gray leaves (according to Google).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few that come to mind but need more context on type of game:

captain - makes on field decision for teams

coach - makes decision on players and strategy

game-master - used role playing games

manager - used as a synonym for coach but used more in the gaming world